# How do I find the Sitecore Rocks (Hard Rock) Service config?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-rocks

Trying to connect to sitecore rocks.  Good Old Webservice works fine.  Hard Rock service returns the following error:

```
For TransferMode.Buffered, MaxReceivedMessageSize and MaxBufferSize 
must be the same value.  Parameter name:binding element.
```

I've managed to find the client config in the following folder.

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks\Connections
```

I suspect this is ok because I've deleted and re-created the connection but I'm really struggling to find the service endpoint config.  I think the endpoint is here:

```
\sitecore\shell\WebService\Service2.asmx
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: For the record I've just managed to fix my problem so typing this up incase it helps someone else.  I ended up deleting the contents of that Connections folder, restarting visual studio and creating a new connection again from scratch.  Now it works.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it resolved.  Anyway, I would like to try Sitecore Rocks, so this info is useful to me.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a fab tool.  My favourite bits are the Query Analyzer and the package manager (where you can package up dependencies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete contents of connections folder, restart VS, create a new connection again from scratch.